# Lambda to create EC2 machine using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I am using lambda to create ec2 machine using boto3. I need to give the instance an IAM role. In boto3 we give the IAM role via `InstanceProfiles` but when we create a role that has access to Lambda no instance profiles come up.

So how do we achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to:

- Use [`create_instance_profile()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.create_instance_profile) to create a named profile
- Use [`add_role_to_instance_profile()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.add_role_to_instance_profile) to associate an IAM Role with the Instance Profile
- Provide the Instance Profile when launching the Amazon EC2 instance